# Elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the ‘class’ keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, enum-class, elaborated-type-specifier

I have the following enum specification:

```
enum class FaceDirection : int8
{
  Down,
  Up
};
```

g++ 4.8.1 gives the following error:

> warning: elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the ‘class’ keyword

What causes this?

Comment: Next time, try clang++ ;) *"error: unknown type name 'int8'; did you mean 'int'?"*

Comment: @DyP, I keep hearing good things about clang. This would actually be a suitable project to try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Would be awesome if you posted a bug report for GCC too!

Comment: @polkadotcadaver, good idea. [Done](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59423).

Comment: To complete the set: MS C++ gives *"C3064 - 'int8': must be a simple type or resolve to one"*

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Check the type you are deriving the `enum class` from exists. In this case, there was no typedef specified for `int8`.

Comment: Still helpful! Forgot to include `<cstddef>` when scoping an answer relating to scoped enums of `std::ptrdiff_t` and this saved me a while ^_^

Comment: `#include <cstdint>` did it for me