# 'enum struct' won't compile unless <iostream> is included

Tags: c++11, struct, enums, include, enum-class

I have code that contains the line

```
enum struct cols: int8_t {red, blue, green};
```

When i compile this, i  get errors:

```
test.cpp:4:1: warning: elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the 'struct' keyword
 enum struct cols: int8_t {red, blue, green};
 ^
test.cpp:4:13: error: use of enum 'cols' without previous declaration
 enum struct cols: int8_t {red, blue, green};
             ^
test.cpp:4:17: error: expected unqualified-id before ':' token
 enum struct cols: int8_t {red, blue, green};
                 ^
```

However if i put the line

```
#include <iostream>
```

at the top, it compiles without complaint.

Is there an explanation for this?

(I am using g++ 4.9.4, but this behaviour is also displayed with g++ 5.4.0.)

Answer (score 1):

`std::int8_t` is not a built-in type. It is, like all other exact-width types, an optional typedef to a built-in type, present only if your system has an appropriate type of that width. This and other available `std::[u]int*_t` types are defined in `<cstdint>`. Therefore, you need to `#include <cstdint>`.

As my above paragraph indicates, you should also specify the `std::` namespace qualifier, as stdlib symbols in the `<c*>` headers are not required to be made available in the global namespace.

Presumably `<iostream>` was previously indirectly including `<cstdint>` by some route, but you should not rely on that; you should `#include` the correct header for every library symbol you use.

Then the thing about `struct` is a red herring arising from the other, main problem of the unknown underlying type; see [Elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the ‘class’ keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459120/elaborated-type-specifier-for-a-scoped-enum-must-not-use-the-class-keyword), which now that I look at it, is nearly an exact duplicate of your question.